# Handling huge amount of MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a JS script that does one simple thing - an ajax request to my server. On this server I establish a PDO connection, execute one prepared statement:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE param1 = :param1 AND param2 = :param2;`

Where `table` is the table with 5-50 rows, 5-15 columns, with data changing once each day on average.

Then I echo the json result back to the script and do something with it, let's say I console log it.

---

The problem is that the script is run ~10,000 times a second. Which gives me that much connections to the database, and I'm getting `can't connect to the database` errors all the time in server logs. Which means sometimes it works, when DB processes are free, sometimes not.

How can I handle this?

Probable solutions:

1. Memcached - it would also be slow, it's not created to do that. The performance would be similar, or worse, to the database.
2. File on server instead of the database - great solution, but the structure would be the problem.

Anything better?

Comment: I guess you are trying to create a new dbs connection for each request. Have a look at persistant connection in PDO. Also at the same time if there is a huge trafic usually load balancing is used to distribute the requests and maintain availability of data.

Comment: How is a file on the server slower than memcached? and whats the problem in creating JSON encoded data with a cronjob?
This does sound like classic work for memory caching

If you are trying to scale you should separate the DB server from the frontend servers and install memcache on them.
That way -- even if you get identical performance from memcache -- you can distribute it on cheap frontend servers instead of bombarding your poor database.

You are complaining about bottlenecks here, not about latencies -- don't really see how performance matters in this case.

Comment: Also the use of memcached should be decided on what your dbs structure is. For example i would never use caching in authentication but i would definately use it to display content of blog which is same for everyone and seldom changes

Comment: Memcached is slower than file on server is what I meant (said).

Comment: Have you considered caching outputs instead of the data itself ?
No reason to keep running the same PHP script if the results are the same .. just pre-generate the output and use PHP just for authentication ( if you even need that ) > you can store the results on a ramdisk.
Also, please add the reasons why using memcached/file/output cache is not good in your case in the question , it's a bit vague as it stands

Comment: 1.) How do you console log a JS script with database access? this isn't client side
2.) What server do you use ?
3.) Is this nodejs?
4.) If you have a limited number of results , cache the script result in a regular temporary file on a ramdisk or memcached and only output the correct result that the user needs.
If you have 10,000 queries per second this would make sense even for a large result set ( even 100k results is nothing for a memory cache for that amount of rows )

Comment: I guess your problem is not number of connections. show your `CREATE TABLE` statement for that table please. And you are completely wrong about memcached performance. in your case performance could be 100 faster than db. But you don't need it. And show us your php script that is on charge for this ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

For such a tiny amount of data that is changed so rarely, I'd make it just a regular PHP file.

Once you have your data in the form of array, dump it in the php file using `var_export()`. Then just include this file and use a simple loop to search data.

Another option is to use Memcached, which was created exactly this sort of job and on a fast machine with high speed networking, memcached can easily handle 200,000+ requests per second, which is high above your modest 10k rps.

You can even eliminate PHP from the tract, making Nginx directly ask Memcached for the stored valaues, using ngx_http_memcached_module

If you want to stick with current Mysql-based solution, you can increase `max_connections` number in mysql configuration, however, making it above 200 would may require some OS tweaking as well. But what you should not is to make a persistent connection, that will make things far worse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage a cache.  There is no reason at all to go fetch the data from the database every time the AJAX request is made for data that is this slow-changing.

A couple of approaches that you could take (possibly even in combination with each other).

Cache between application and DB.  This might be memcache or similar and would allow you to perform hash-based lookups (likely based on some hash of parameters passed) to data stored in memory (perhaps JSON representation or whatever data format you ultimately return to the client).

Cache between client and application.  This might take the form of web-server-provided cache, a CDN-based cache, or similar that would prevent the request from ever even reaching your application given an appropriately stored, non-expired item in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Anything better? No

Since you output the same results many times, the sensible solution is to cache results.

My educated guess is your wrong assumption -- that memcached is not built for this -- is based off you planning on storing each record separately

I implemented a simple caching mechanism for you to use :

```
    <?php
    $memcached_port = YOUR_MEMCACHED_PORT;

    $m = new Memcached();
    $m->addServer('localhost', $memcached_port);

    $key1 = $_GET['key1'];
    $key2 = $_GET['key2'];

    $m_key = $key1.$key2; // generate key from unique values , for large keys use MD5 to hash the unique value

    $data = false;
    if(!($data = $m->get($m_key))) {
        // fetch $data from your database
        $expire = 3600; // 1 hour, you may use a unix timestamp value if you wish to expire in a specified time of day
        $m->set($m_key,$data,$expire); // push to memcache
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

What you do is :

1. Decide on what signifies a result ( what set of input parameters )
2. Use that for the memcache key ( for example if it's a country and language the key would be $country.$language )
3. check if the result exists:

   - if it does pull the data you stored as an array and output it.
   - if it doesn't exist or is outdated :

   a. pull the data needed

   b. put the data in an array

   c. push the data to memcached

   d. output the data

There are more efficient ways to cache data, but this is the simplest one, and sounds like your kind of code.

10,000 requests/second still don't justify the effort needed to create server-level caching ( nginx/whatever )
In an ideally tuned world a chicken with a calculator would be able to run facebook .. but who cares ? (: